# Utility for entering partitions into fstab

Tags: partitioning, fstab

Under Windows it's possible to create a symbolic name for a disk partition by assigning it a drive letter.  It's certainly possible to do that in (K)ubuntu by editing /etc/fstab and inserting the appropriate entry, but that's inelegant compared with the way it's done in Windows.  Is there a way to do the same with a higher-level utility such as the KDE Partition Manager?  The KDE Partition Manager does understand mount points but doesn't have a way of inserting them into fstab if they aren't already there, as far as I can tell.

I asked this question a couple of years ago and didn't get any answers, but the situation may have improved since then.

Comment: The GNOME DIsk Utility can do this. Are you looking for KDE-specific programs?

Comment: Does the Gnome Disk Utility run under KDE?  A KDE-specific program would be better, but that might work.

Comment: It will run under KDE, but it might depend on quite a few gnome libraries). I'm not familiar enough with the KDE ecosystem, though.

Comment: I installed gnome-disk-utility and called gnome-disks, but it appeared to be passive -- giving information but not providing a means of changing anything.

Comment: There is a gear icon beneath the partition layout. Once you select a partition, there should be an option to edit mount options in that menu.

Comment: Yes, I see it -- but it's all greyed out.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

With GNOME Disks Utility:

[image]
Usually, it will have *Automatic Mount Options* enabled. Disable it, and set your options:

[image]